# Accessing environment variables in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where I am trying to use values of some environment variables. Those variables are defined - I see the keys and values if I run `printenv`.

Also, these variables are defined and exported like
`export FOO="bar"`
in both ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc.

I am trying to execute the script via `./script-name` which fails to get the environment variables. If I run `sudo -E ./script-name`, that somehow gets the script the variables it needs.

Confused as to why these variables aren't available to the script even when they are exported in above files.

Comment: Did you add #!/bin/bash as shebang? Also double check "wich bash" if it's in /bin/

Comment: @upInCloud: If you see the variables with `printenv` immediately before calling your script, they are also in the environment inside the script. Place a `printenv´ as the first executable statement of your script to verify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of, is that for some reason, the shell process which you are calling to run the script, does not have full read access to your current environment.

```
ls -al /usr/bin/bash
ls -al /bin/sh
```

Assuming neither of them are symlinks, make sure that your current user has read and execute priveleges.  A safer (in security terms) option, would be for you to install bash in ~/opt, and use #!~/opt/bin/bash as your shebang line.

Comment: seems like this is the problem as I am able to get this working on another machine. The machine I was doing this earlier on was a provisioned VM with maybe less privileges or some security configuration.